# Interface variable in HTML works but throws console TypeError?

Tags: json, angular

What can I do to get rid of this error?

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'feed' of undefined
```

I have:

1. An Interface (SpreadsheetTabs) that defines some complex JSON from a google spreadsheet
2. A Service that properly returns the JSON as that interface type

spreadsheet-tabs.service.ts

```
getTabs(): Promise<SpreadsheetTabs> {
    return this.http.get(this.tabsUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => this.extractData(response.json() as SpreadsheetTabs[] ))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SpreadsheetTabs } from '../models/SpreadsheetTabs';
import { SpreadsheetTabsService } from '../services/spreadsheet-tabs.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  theTabs: SpreadsheetTabs;
  constructor(private spreadsheetTabsService: SpreadsheetTabsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.spreadsheetTabsService.getTabs()
      .then(tabs => {

        // assign results returned to variable
        this.theTabs = tabs;

        // I can loop through here - no errors
        for (const oneTab of this.theTabs.feed.entry) {
          console.log(oneTab.title.$t + ' - ' + oneTab.link[0].href + '?alt=json');
        }
      });

  }
}
```

home.component.html

```
<p>
  loop also works here, but throws console TypeError above
</p>
<h3>tabs list:</h3>
<div *ngFor="let oneTab of theTabs.feed.entry">
    <h4>{{oneTab.title.$t + ' - ' + oneTab.link[0].href + '?alt=json'}}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Add your SpreadsheetTabs interface code

Comment: too large to post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the safe navigation operator (?) in your template, so that if `theTabs` is null or undefined, it won't try to get the value of feed:

```
*ngFor="let oneTab of theTabs?.feed.entry"
```

From [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths):

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient
>   way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

Don't get confused with the null coalescing operator from other languages.  This is specific to template processing and not part of typescript.  Alternatively you could just default `theTabs` to an empty array, but the problem with that is that you have to always make sure that the result of `getTabs()` also always returns an array (or just use `||`: `this.theTabs = tabs || []`).

Comment: Wow that worked, THANKS!

The TypeError is gone, but the loop works as expected

Answer (score 0):

In typescript You can initialize the interface by assigning some default values to the property

`heTabs: SpreadsheetTabs={feed=[] };`

You can also handle the null and undefined in your angular template with a Safe Navigation Operator also

You can read more about this operator from template syntax documentation section
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax